# How to create a check if record does not exists in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I want to show the county in the following query but if county does not exist, return the city instead.

```
        SELECT P.id  AS id, SUM(P.price)  AS price, 
                    P.tax, 
                    county  
                FROM Purchases AS  P
                JOIN Status  AS S       ON S.id = T.status_id
                JOIN Shipping AS Ship   ON S.shipping_id= Ship.id
                JOIN Shipping_Addresses AS  SA      ON Ship.shipping_address_id = SA.id
                JOIN Zip_Codes          AS ZIP      ON ZIP.zip_code = SA.zip_code
                JOIN Counties           AS C        ON ZIP.city = C.city
                JOIN States             AS STATE    ON STATE.id = C.county_state_id

                GROUP BY ZIP.zip_code
                ORDER BY county
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [**`COALESCE()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
COALESCE(county, city) AS location
```

If `county` is `NULL` it will return the value of `city` instead.

So:

```
SELECT P.id  AS id, SUM(P.price)  AS price, 
    P.tax, 
    COALESCE(county, city) AS location
```

Comment: If this answer works for you make sure to click the green check mark next to it to accept it as the correct answer

Comment: I will do so as soon as possible. It does not let me accept it just yet, I have to wait for a couple of minutes